# Find frequencies and durations

Tags: python, pandas, frequency, duration

I have less experience with pandas/python, however, I would like to learn. Hopefully, anyone is prepared and able to help.

What does my data look like:
Several participants 'participant' are included which each is divided into 16 conditions 'condition'. Each condition takes 40 seconds 'matchtimesm'. 'Median' is between 0 and 1 whether they looked at a tv-screen (>0) or not (0).

First, I would like to find the frequency of looking at the tv-screen per participant and condition. Where following observations >0 counts as one view.

Second, I would like to find the duration 'matchtimesm' of each frequency of looking at the tv-screen per participant and condition.

See a short overview of the dataset. I show you the crucial datapoints here:

```
participant condition matchtimesm median
2           1         0           .1892867
2           1         .367        .188542
2           1         .602        0
2           1         9.86        0
2           1         9.875       .3661981
2           1         9.926       .3836426
2           1         9.942       0
2           2         0           .2000273
2           2         .183        .1112688
2           2         .203        0 
2           2         5.261       0 
2           2         5.281       .2438091
2           2         5.531       .2051106
2           2         5.546       0 
3           1         0           .259453
3           1         3.567       .1714279
3           1         3.582       0 
3           1         22.032      0 
3           1         22.051      .1650706
3           1         22.598      .1336484
3           1         22.617      0
```

I hope you get the point.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby(['participant','condition']).size()

df.groupby(['participant','condition'])['matchtimesm'].sum() #, looks like you want some aggregation here, most likely sum.
```